# how to find mongodb field size of type array

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection called location in mongodb. In location, one field called proiList is there which is an array containing integers. 
location
{
locId:

proiList[]:

} like this....for a particular locId how can I find the lenght ( size ) of the proiList ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aggregation framework for this. Suppose you have a document like this.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50987d7fa3c435bb040eb577"), "hobbies" : [  "bad",  "good",  "tier" ], "score" : 54.6535436362647, "student_id" : 0, "type" : "exam" }
```

and we want to calculate the number of hobbies that the students have then we can write the query as:

```
db.grades.aggregate([{$match:{"_id":ObjectId("50987d7fa3c435bb040eb577")}},{$unwind:"$hobbies"},{$group:{_id:"$_id", number:{$sum:1}}}]);
```

Result:

```
{
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("50987d7fa3c435bb040eb577"),
        "number" : 3
    }
],
"ok" : 1
```

}

where number is the total number of hobbies.

Step1: db.grades.aggregate([{$unwind:"$hobbies"}]) results in unwinding the array:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("50906d7fa3c412bb040eb577"),
            "hobbies" : "bad",
            "score" : 54.6535436362647,
            "student_id" : 0,
            "type" : "exam"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("50906d7fa3c412bb040eb577"),
            "hobbies" : "good",
            "score" : 54.6535436362647,
            "student_id" : 0,
            "type" : "exam"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("50906d7fa3c412bb040eb577"),
            "hobbies" : "tier",
            "score" : 54.6535436362647,
            "student_id" : 0,
            "type" : "exam"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Step:2 We group by _id:"$_id" and add number key for the output which return the $sum for all the number of documents in the group.

```
db.grades.aggregate([{$unwind:"$hobbies"},{$group:{_id:"$_id", number:{$sum:1}}}])
```

Step3: Add $match to your query to the exact document and in your case it would be locId

```
db.grades.aggregate([{$match:{"_id":ObjectId("50987d7fa3c435bb040eb577")}},{$unwind:"$hobbies"},{$group:{_id:"$_id", number:{$sum:1}}}]);
```

so the number of documents are 3.

Comment: there may be many students with different student_id. how to put the condition ? I mean how to know the number of hobbies for a particular student_id ?

Comment: Okies, I got the issue, even i have modified the above answer:`db.grades.aggregate([{$unwind:"$hobbies"},{$group:{_id:null, number:{$sum:1}}}]);` this will shows count for each group and then we can add $match to get the exact document